# Cannot redeclare function() previously declared - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a script working where a comment is sent which includes a price. An **observer.php** monitoring `checkout_cart_product_add_after`, extracts the price and uses it to increase the original product price.

This all works great!

```
    <?php

class YBizz_PriceChange_Model_Observer  {

public function change_price(Varient_Event_Observer $obs) {

    $quote = $obs->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $custom = $obs->getQuoteItem();
    $product_id=$custom->getProductId();

//Get $str        
$items = null;
$files = array();
$hlp = Mage::helper('orderattachment');
$obAll = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getObjProducts();
if(is_object($obAll)) $items = @$obAll->getItems();
if(!empty($items))
{
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $it = $item->getData();
        if($product_id == intval($it['set_product_id'])) $files[] = $it;
    }
}    
foreach($files as $file){
$str = $file['set_comment'];

//Extract Price from $str
$from = "£";
$to = "]";

function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to)
{
$sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
}
$var =  getStringBetween($str,$from,$to);

//Calc Custom Price
    $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $newprice=$_product->getPrice()+$var;

// Set the custom price
    $custom->setCustomPrice($newprice);
    $custom->setOriginalCustomPrice($newprice);

// Enable super mode on the product.
    $custom->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

}

}

}
```

However, what I need is if an additional comment is sent, this too will also add to the total product price.

Currently, everytime I attempt to send another comment, I get the fatal error message:

```
Cannot redeclare runMyFunction() (previously declared...
```

or

```
Cannot redeclare getStringBetween() (previously declared...
```

I look forward to any assistance you can offer.

Comment: It is telling you what is wrong clearly. There is nothing to answer here

Comment: to reiterate @samaYo "...what I need is if an additional comment is sent, this too will also add to the total product price." I am aware of the problem, I would like assistance resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getStringBetween` function is defined in the `change_price` function. Every time `change_price` is called, it tries to redefine `getStringBetween` but it can't because it's already been defined. Move `getStringBetween` outside of `change_price`. I would assume `runMyFunction` is defined similarly.